# $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)g(x)=0$ for all continuous function $g$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

**Question**

Define a sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ on $[0,1]$ as:
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=0\\1&\text{if } x\in \left(\frac{2k}{2^n}, \frac{2k+1}{2^n}\right],&k=0,1,\cdots,2^{n-1}-1\\-1&\text{if } x\in \left(\frac{2k+1}{2^n}, \frac{2k+2}{2^n}\right],&k=0,1,\cdots,2^{n-1}-1\end{cases}.$$

Prove or disprove that we always have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)g(x)dx=0$$ as long as $g$ is a continuous function.

---

I want to show that when $g_m(x)=x^m$, the equation holds. Then apply Weierstrass Approximation theorem and interchange the limit by Dominated convergence theorem. However, the case $g_m(x)=x^m$ is quite hard to verify.

Comment: Writing $x=1$ and $x=-1$ in the definition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Gary Tks for the correction!

Comment: Have you previously done the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?  If so, you are probably supposed to imitate that proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can provide a seemingly flawed solution.

Suppose $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so it is uniformly continuous. Given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists n$, such that $|x_1-x_2|<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\implies|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|<\epsilon$, $\forall x_1,x_2\in[0,1]$.
We can divide the integration region into $2^n$ segments and combine them in pairs.
$$\bigg|\int_0^1f_n(x)g(x)dx\bigg|=\bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\left(\int_{\frac{2k}{2^n}}^{\frac{2k+1}{2^n}}g(x)dx-\int_{\frac{2k+1}{2^n}}^{\frac{2k+2}{2^n}}g(x)dx\right)\bigg|\\
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\bigg|\int_{\frac{2k}{2^n}}^{\frac{2k+1}{2^n}}g(x)dx-\int_{\frac{2k+1}{2^n}}^{\frac{2k+2}{2^n}}g(x)dx\bigg|
=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{1}{2^n}|g(\xi_k)-g(\eta_k)|<\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^n}\epsilon,$$
where the last $=$ is because of the mean value theorem.

But if $g$ is infinite at the endpoints, I don’t know how to deal with it. I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: By $f$, do you mean $g$? Btw $g$ cannot be infinite at the endpoints since it is continuous on a closed interval and hence it is bounded.